# Hp Fortify: Path Manipulation erroe

Tags: c#, fortify

I am getting the hp fortify warning for the following code:

```
        FileStream fs = null;
        StreamWriter writer = null;

        try
        {
            fs = new FileStream(sFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);// Path Manipulation error
            writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
```

I am not deleting the file in my code, So if user provide the path of some config its safe from my code, So I am not sure why this is giving warning?

Can anyone please suggest me any alternative?

Comment: What is the issue that Fortify is reporting?

Comment: Path Manipulation error

Answer (score 1):

Fortify doesn't know what the file is, where it is, or anything else.  Write the code in a way that Fortify can see that the application is protected from malicious users.

Validate the path so that I can't pass a file named `../../../../cmdshell.aspx`, don't rely on filesystem permissions.  I'm assuming that at some later time you want to read that file, do the same kind of validation there.

I would also validate MIME type, file size, and check for weird characters.